# how to make a background-image set in an element, moved vertically while scrolling?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would know how to make a background-image set in an element like this

```
<div style="background-image:url('/assets/img/homepage-news.jpg')"></div>
```

moved verticaly when the user is scrolling down/up on the page ?

Thank you.

Comment: you mean parallax or does the background image have to stay still when you scroll?

Comment: Yes A kind of parallax. You have the body, and then in the middle of the page or whatever, you have the div i show you in my answer with width at 100% and height at 300px for example.
You set a background-image in css, and when I scroll the picture move vertically (so it scroll too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
div {
background: url('/assets/img/homepage-news.jpg') fixed no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

You can see an example at [sheljawedsanuj.in](http://sheljawedsanuj.in/)

Answer (score -1):

Just set a background image and then insert another div that scrolls with you with fixed options.
See for example: http://davidwalsh.name/css-fixed-position

Or look at my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/tLqzdbkd/`enter code here`

Comment: Thanks, but that really not what I asked.